Safari: Can I always open a URL in a web app?
When I create a wep app in Safari with "Add to dock..." for e.g. stackoverflow.com, I'd like to have all links to Stackoverflow open in the web app instead of a normal Safari window.
Is there a way to do that?

Welcome to Ask Different.  When you say all links - do you mean if you are in a notes app and have saved links, the call out from other apps should select the “docked safari with a home page set” over the safari app? Or are you in safari or another browser and want a link that opens a new tab or browser window to not do that and send it to the dock?

Ideally both, but catching links only from other Safari windows would still help a little. One typical scenario is that I get links in an email to pull requests on Bitbucket or Jira tickets and want them to open in my docked Bitbucket window or Jira window respectively.

Apple has added this feature in macOS Sequoia :) https://webkit.org/blog/15865/webkit-features-in-safari-18-0/#web-apps-for-mac
It only works when you click a link outside of Safari, though (Mail, Slack etc.) Within Safari, you see a banner at the top of the page with a button "open in web app" after you have clicked a link to a page from a web app.
